# Is there a terminal command that changes the terminal window dimensions?

Tags: command-line, bash

I like having a small terminal for small things (80 x 24), and a big terminal for editing code in vim and such (120 x 38), and sometimes even going full screen, browsing ascci art? I dunno.

Anywho, is there a terminal command that I can use to toggle window sizes for my terminal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. `resize -s <rows> <columns>` works with Ubuntu's default terminal application (`gnome-terminal`).

## How to resize the terminal until a program is finished

To get a nice effect of having, say, `vim` in a specially-sized window only while it's running:

1. `mkdir ~/bin`
2. `~/.profile` by default adds `~/bin` to the `PATH`; For now, you can either `source ~/.profile` or declare the new `PATH` yourself: `export PATH="$PATH":~/bin`
3. `vim ~/bin/vim`
4. Add the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   source <(/usr/bin/resize -s)
   /usr/bin/resize -s 38 120
   /usr/bin/vim "$@"
   /usr/bin/resize -s $LINES $COLUMNS
   ```
5. Save
6. `chmod +x ~/bin/vim`

Now `vim` will run at size 120×38 and the resizing will be undone when `vim` finishes.

Comment: You rock! : ) Is it possible to get this command to work from within vim as well? I tried `!resize -s 38 120` but that didn't work, until I changed a vim flag in my .vimrc, but that made the whole thing choke and do weird graphics things.

Comment: I suppose I can ctrl + z, and toggle, then `fg` back to vim : )

Comment: OK, I've added a small section on how to get, say, `vim` using the same size terminal and then unresizing it after exiting `vim`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when `gnome-terminal` is maximized or snapped to a side/corner. I'm using 14.04.

Comment: In Vim, you can `:set lines=38 columns=120`.

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 16.10 (and maybe older versions too), if you open a terminal window, and go to the `Terminal` menu, you can select alternate window sizes directly. In fact, almost exactly the sizes that you are asking for!

Also, `F11` will toggle full screen mode.

You can also create multiple profiles that set the screen to exactly the size(s) that you want. Go to the `File` menu and choose `New Profile`... call it "My editing profile". Then, when you want to change to a different profile, go to the `Terminal` menu and choose `Change Profile`. Then go to the `Edit` menu and choose `Profile Perferences`. Set your custom screen size there. Different profiles, each with different screen sizes!

Comment: I'm more of a home row keyboard guy : ) This is cool though, thanks!!!

Comment: I have ubunutu 20.04.2 and the "terminal menu" is nowhere to be seen Groetjes Albert

Comment: @AlbertvanderHorst In newer versions of Ubuntu, you'll have to use the Preferences, and edit the "Default" Profile.